# How to include the ApplicationUser of an object in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make an app just like LinkedIn / Facebook.

I have a list of posts and each one has an `ApplicationUser` (ASP.NET `IdentityUser`).

In my `PostController`, I want to return the list of posts and include the `ApplicationUser`.

But I don't want every attribute of the user as an object containing a (hashed) password.

How can I return a post including `ApplicationUser` but without the password attribute?

`Post.cs`

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Contents { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ulong Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

`PostController`:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Post>> GetPost(int id)
{
    var post = await _context.Posts
                             .Include(x=> x.ApplicationUser)
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    if (post == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return post;
}
```

`ApplicationUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

Comment: Don't return database types directly at all. Define some specific model for your api, map your Post/User entity and return them. You will have much less trouble in the future.

Comment: Two ways: **(1)** either just set the `Password` attribute to `NULL` after you've fetched the post with the associated `ApplicationUser` - or **(2)** create a separate class that contains just the attribute of `ApplicationUser` you want and in your Linq query, use a `.select(x => new AppUserMinimal......)` statement to project only those attributes you want and need to that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view model which included the required properties, such as below:

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Contents { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ulong Timestamp { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; } //Directly add the username property, used to store the user name

    public UserViewModel User { get; set; } //create a new view model which contains the username
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, change the LINQ statement as as below:

```
var query = _dbcontext.Posts.Include(c => c.ApplicationUser)
               .Select(c => new PostViewModel()
               {
                   Id = c.Id,
                   Contents = c.Contents,
                   Timestamp = c.Timestamp,
                   UserName = c.ApplicationUser.UserName,
                   User = new UserViewModel()
                   {
                       UserName = c.ApplicationUser.UserName
                   } 
               }).ToList();
```

The result as below:

[image]